# Does a variable initialized in a for loop get reset every iteration?

Tags: c++, initialization

```
for (i=0;i<=n;i++) {
       fsten[i]=fx(xsten[i]); //fsten[0] = fx(xsten[0]); fsten[1] = fx(xsten[1]); ...; etc. initializing the fsten array up to n times.
} //end of initial for loop

      y=0.0;

      for (i=0;i<=n;i++) {
       L=1.0; //the lagrange basis polynomial
           for (j=0;j<=n;j++) {
                if (i!=j) {
                 L=L*(x-xsten[j])/(xsten[i]-xsten[j]);
                } //end of if statement
           } //end of second for loop
       y=y+fsten[i]*L;
      }//end of first for loop
```

I am doing a Lagrange polynomial iteration. We are looking at the second for loop after the y=0.0. At the end of the for loop with the `j=0`, we have `y = y+fsten[i]*L` where L is obviously not `1` anymore. But when it goes to `i=1` does that mean that the L=1.0 is true again?

Comment: are you asking if all your statements are run each pass in a loop? Yes, of course they are.

Comment: _"Does a variable initialized in a for loop get reset every iteration?"_ **YES!** (unless you introduce a `static` variable)

Comment: You could have determined this yourself with a very simple experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is true again, because you run the body of the loop again and `L = 1.0` does set the variable `L` to `1.0`.